# When Button clicked Display next image in directory

Tags: python-3.x, click, pyqt5, python-itertools

I am trying to create a program in Python that allows to Load an image in MainWin and then allows to change the image by clicking Next and thus displaying the next image in the folder. When Next reaches end of files in folder it should jump to beginning of folder. I managed to Load the image and even change the image with Next but only once - if i click Next again the picture doesnt change anymore. Any idea why please ? thanks

```
  self.LoadImage.clicked.connect(self.LoadImg)
  self.NextImage.clicked.connect(self.NextImg)

def LoadImg(self):
    global directory
    global filename
    directory = 'C:/Users/mario/Desktop/desktop 17112019 2/New Folder'
    filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Select Image', directory, 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg)')
    if filename:  # If the user gives a file
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filename)  # Setup pixmap with the provided image
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.label.width(), self.label.height(),
                               QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)  # Scale pixmap
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)  # Set the pixmap onto the label
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)  # Align the label to center


def vec(self):
    a = os.listdir(directory)
    k = a.index(os.path.basename(filename))
    imageList = a[k:] + a[:k]
    return imageList

def NextImg(self):
    pool = itertools.cycle(self.vec())
    print(next(pool))
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(directory + '/' + next(pool))  # Setup pixmap with the provided image
    pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.label.width(), self.label.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)  
    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)  # Set the pixmap onto the label
    self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)  # Align the label to center
```

Edit: i suspect i need to break the connection between the chosen file with LoadImage and cycle iterator but dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use globals, expecially with sensitive and "general use" names like `directory`. I also suggest you to never use capitalized names for functions and variables.

To keep track of the current file and cycle through the contents of the directory, use a class attribute instead.

In this example I'm using a python iterator starting from the contents of the selected file directory, each time the "next" button is pressed it the next item of the iterator is loaded, and if the iterator has reached its end it will generate a new one.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ImageLoader(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        # the label alignment property is always maintained even when the contents
        # change, so there is no need to set it each time
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.loadImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load image')
        layout.addWidget(self.loadImageButton, 1, 0)

        self.nextImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Next image')
        layout.addWidget(self.nextImageButton)

        self.loadImageButton.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        self.nextImageButton.clicked.connect(self.nextImage)

        self.dirIterator = None
        self.fileList = []

    def loadImage(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Select Image', '', 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg)')
        if filename:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filename).scaled(self.label.size(), 
                QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            if pixmap.isNull():
                return
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            dirpath = os.path.dirname(filename)
            self.fileList = []
            for f in os.listdir(dirpath):
                fpath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                if os.path.isfile(fpath) and f.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                    self.fileList.append(fpath)
            self.fileList.sort()
            self.dirIterator = iter(self.fileList)
            while True:
                # cycle through the iterator until the current file is found
                if next(self.dirIterator) == filename:
                    break

    def nextImage(self):
        # ensure that the file list has not been cleared due to missing files
        if self.fileList:
            try:
                filename = next(self.dirIterator)
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filename).scaled(self.label.size(), 
                    QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                if pixmap.isNull():
                    # the file is not a valid image, remove it from the list
                    # and try to load the next one
                    self.fileList.remove(filename)
                    self.nextImage()
                else:
                    self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            except:
                # the iterator has finished, restart it
                self.dirIterator = iter(self.fileList)
                self.nextImage()
        else:
            # no file list found, load an image
            self.loadImage()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    imageLoader.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @mavish can you explain what you mean by "incorrect"?

Comment: The fpath variable stores incorrect paths C:/Users\address.jpg so i replaced it with fpath = dirpath + '/' + f. I also imagine the conditions if os.path.isfile(fpath) and f.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')): are not really necessary since the user can only click on diplayed files which are 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg)') (i also added  *.JPG since some of my pics have this extension. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: That's due to the different way Qt and python manage file paths on windows (which uses the annoying backslash instead of standard slash). I suggest you to use `os.sep.join((dirpath, f))` for these situations. The if conditions instead are necessary: the file list is generated on the *full* contents of the directory (it doesn't know anything about the file filters used in the dialog), so you might end up with subdirectories and unrecognized file types.